# Changing design layout in realtime?

Tags: xcode

Just curious - is it possible to change the color/design of elements in storyboard and see them reflected on the app that is running?

For example, changing the background color of a label, and then seeing that result on my iPhone (assuming Xcode is currently running the app) WITHOUT rebuilding the whole app?

Comment: I don't think so, not unless you add a way for the app user to change the colors themselves. Suggested alternative: Make a mockup of your design in a graphics program and change the colors in that instead.

Comment: It's not quite what you asked about, but have you looked at `IBDesignable`? It allows Xcode to show you a live preview in its own GUI of your custom views.

Answer (score 0):

You want to see changes made in your source reflected in the application running on your device, without having to rebuild and deploy the app (I think). If so, you cannot do that at this time using Xcode and iOS.